# How do you add a text file in IEER?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to make my text file in IEER corpus format so that I can use the functions `extract_rels()` and `parsed_docs()` directly. How to do that? I am using python and NLTK.

### What I tried

```
ws = nltk.corpus.reader.ieer.IEERCorpusReader(corpus_root, 'doc1.txt') 

print ws.fileids() #ws is a instantaneous of ieer corpus 

RELATION=re.compile(r'\bin\b') 

for t in ws.fileids(): 

 for doc in ws.parsed_docs(t): 

     for rel in nltk.sem.extract_rels('PER', 'LOC', doc , corpus='ieer', pattern=RELATION):  

         print nltk.sem.clause(rel, relsym= 'RELATION' )
```

I did this but no output is coming and also no error..

**doc1.txt**

`Peter in India. Ajay in London. John in Madrid`

Comment: This would be a better question if you explained what you have tried already. Have you read the documentation? What is confusing?

Comment: in doc1.txt---->Peter in India.
Ajay in London.
John in Madrid